# No error when using pointer after deleting the dynamically allocated memory it points at

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic, allocation

I'm learning about dynamic memory in C++. My question is why after removing the variable in the following code I don't get an error?

```
float* uf = new float(4.26);
delete uf;
cout << uf << '\n';
cout << *uf << '\n';
```

Comment: Because it's *undefined behavior*, and UB can sometimes seem to work perfectly well when in fact it's not.

Comment: Dereferencing the pointer after deletion triggers an undefined behavior. An undefined behavior can remain unnoticed, trigger a segmentation fault, or produce strange outputs... This is why programmers spend so much time debugging their code !

Comment: Yes, instead of 4.26, I get a weird number, same as I did "float a; cout << a;"..

Comment: The weird number is coming from some memory block in the memory space dedicated to your process. Omho in such scenarios the best outcome is for your application to crash (due to segmentation fault) because otherwise you might totally miss it and for example spend hours trying to figure out why you're getting this and that result when the application compiles fine and algorithm-wise you don't see any issues.

A common practice when dealing with pointers is to nullify the pointer variable right after you have released the memory it is pointing at by setting it to NULL.

Comment: Btw I don't see the point why this question has been downvoted. It's a legit question and except for the way it was formulated (I've edited a little bit) it's fine.

Comment: @rbaleksand: This is not common practice. I think it was, about 20 years ago. In modern C++, you avoid direct use of dynamic allocation; it's all managed by container classes or `unique_ptr` et al, or you do `delete this` in an event-handling system. In none of those scenarios does it make sense or is it even possible to set a pointer to `NULL` (mind that it should also be `nullptr` in modern C++).

Comment: "avoid direct use of dynamic allocation" Nonsense. It depends on what you are doing. Not every situation requires the usage of container classes or `unique_ptr`. And yes, using NULL in such scenarios is not required but those scenarios are not ALL scenarios out there. Depending on the task you might avoid using dynamically allocated memory completely (working with embedded systems for instance). Also maintenance of legacy code is a task a programmer might have to face quite often. Not every one writes in C++11 or even 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean because it compiles even though it's clearly wrong?

Arguably, in this case the compiler could produce a warning if it really wanted to, but then it's a simplified, unrealistic situation.

Consider the following example:

```
float* uf = new float(4.26);
delete uf;
if (random_condition_known_only_at_runtime()) {
    uf = new float(0.0);
}
cout << uf << '\n';
cout << *uf << '\n';
```

Or:

```
float* uf = new float(4.26);
if (user_input == 'x') {
    delete uf;
}
cout << uf << '\n';
cout << *uf << '\n';
```

Or consider concurrency; multiple threads may write to the same pointer.

The point is that real code will typically depend (directly or indirectly) a lot on I/O operations or other external state like this, making it impossible to know in advance, at compile time, whether the memory pointed to will have been deleted already.

---

Or do you mean because the program doesn't crash? That's because the C++ standard does not prescribe crashes. It instead refers to "undefined behaviour", which means that anything can happen, including random crashes or no effect at all. Trying to access memory which was already deleted is a classical example of such undefined behaviour.

Comment: Although due to the nature of the question (category: new to C/C++ programming) involving the concept of multi-threading is completely unnecessary and hindering.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: There is no "C/C++ programming". The question is not about C anyway. And being new to C++ does not mean that someone was never exposed to multi-threading before.

Comment: Okay the C/C++ part I mentioned was unnecessary but this doesn't change the essence of the question. "does not mean that someone was never exposed to multi-threading before" True, but assuming that everyone posting questions here has, is even worse.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: So, why is it bad to even hint at the existence of multi-threading (which since C++11 is officially part of the language, too)? This is clearly a case of "keep in mind that such a thing exists, even if it's still too early for you to dig deeper".

Comment: It adds another layer of complexity which is not required here (even as "keep in mind ..." sort of thing).

Answer (score 1):

You don't get an error at *compile time*, because while the compiler tries to detect straightforward mistakes, it can't possibly know, at any given time, weather or not your pointer points to valid memory or not.

You may not get an error at *run time*, because even though the memory has been "freed", it is still memory. It's just not guaranteed to be yours anymore. This is the problem with undefined behavior: it is undefined; you never know exactly how a problem might manifest itself.